# How to filter an array based on words in another array?

Tags: javascript, filter, cpu-word

I want to filter some words contained in an array, contained in a string. For example:

**Inputs**

*1. "disappear" definitions:*

```
[ "Cease to be visible.",
  "Cease to exist or be in use.",
  "Be lost or go missing, become IMPOSSIBLE to find.",
  "Abduct or arrest and kill or detain (a person) for political reasons,
  without making their fate known." ]
```

*2. banned words:*

```
[ 'without', 'impossible' ]
```

**Result**

```
[ "Cease to be visible.", "Cease to exist or be in use." ]
```

I think, I'm very close to the answer:

```
function filterDefinition (defs, badWords) {
  const definitionFilter = defs.filter(function(def) {
    if (def.includes(badWords || badWords.toUpperCase()) {
      return !defs
    }
  });
  return definitionFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
function filterDefinition (defs, badWords) {
  return defs.filter(function(def) {
    return !badWords.some(badWord => def.includes(badWord) || def.includes(badWord.toUpperCase()));
  });
}
```

String.includes(string) does not work on arrays.